# Destroying session bean during lifecycle or at any phase

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

hi I want to destroy my bean at a specific time.Is there a way that can I capture the live bean and set all of its value to NULL for instance If I have a method then I want that the bean will destroy at the end of method execution.How can I do that?

Comment: You can use JSF 2.0 events. Please give more details about the "specific time' and bean scope. It seems to be a use case for Conversations scope.

Comment: Is it a session-scoped bean? You can use a request-scoped bean or conversation-scoped bean. In second case you can just end conversation . Do you use JSF managed beans or CDI beans? In CDI you can annotate a method with `@Remove` annnotation.

Comment: ok let me check about conservation and CDI scopes.. Because request scope didn't fulfill my requirment

Comment: Just use the view scope. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Beans are available to you in different phases.If you want your processing during these phase then you can use `PhaseListener` for this purpose. With this interface and its method , you can get beans at different phases.[Here is the detailed link about phases](http://www.softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-PhaseListeners.htm)
Hope so it will help you.Feel free to ask if you are not clear :)

Comment: where should I call this class?

Comment: This class will be invoked after every phase itself.You just need to register it in faces-config.xml.See the link which I posted.You will get a good detail there